# How to find the files that are last changed under a directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: filesystems

I would like to know how to find the files that are last changed under a directory and its subdirectories.
`ls -lt` doesn't work, because if a file is changed and therefore its time is changed to be up to date, the directory that containing the file will not have its directory updated.

My ultimate goal is to find the last changed file whose size is increasing the fastest or most, for [my problem mentioned in the other post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81363/why-is-the-available-space-in-my-home-decreasing). So I also would like to know about that.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

```
find /search/root -printf "%T+ %10s %p\n" | sort -n --reverse
```

If you use GNU find and no file name (or path) contains a newline (which could be checked by a `-path` test).